# Retrofit multipart request returning empty body

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit, multipart

Currently, I am developing an android app for a company I'm interning with.
What I'm trying to do is to create a form with various fields and images.

I am using `Retrofit` as my networking library to submit the form data to the server.

I followed these tutorials :
[Upload Dynamic amounts of file to server](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-a-dynamic-amount-of-files-to-server)

and
[Passing multiple parameters with @PartMap](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap)

and I combined them both as :

Endpoint

```
@POST("/stockyard/api/add-dealer.php")
Call<ResponseBody> submitForm(@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> textDetails,
                              @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files);
```

MainActivtiy

```
Call<ResponseBody> form = submitRequest.submitForm(formDetails,filesList);
    final ProgressDialog uploadProgress = new ProgressDialog(QuickAddDealer.this);
    uploadProgress.setTitle("Uploading");
    uploadProgress.setMessage("Please Wait while your data is uploaded");
    uploadProgress.create();
    uploadProgress.show();
    form.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                uploadProgress.dismiss();
            try {
                Toast.makeText(QuickAddDealer.this, response.body().string(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(QuickAddDealer.this,t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            uploadProgress.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

The issue is that the request is successful, but the server code doesn't receive any of these. Also the response is empty everytime.

I'm unable to figure out the issue. Please help.

P.S. Earlier, the code would execute OnFailure with the response "Too many follow up requests", but the data would submit to the server successfully. But after some time, this error stopped appearing, and the data would not submit to server.

**EDIT**

The logged request

> 08-12 11:22:13.021 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: --> POST https://glocar.in/developing/stockyard/api/add-dealer.php http/1.1
>   08-12 11:22:13.021 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=7d8bb6d6-ecaa-4e18-b219-0e02ffa04221
>   08-12 11:22:13.026 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 66335
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: --7d8bb6d6-ecaa-4e18-b219-0e02ffa04221
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="created_by"
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 2
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: 30
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: --7d8bb6d6-ecaa-4e18-b219-0e02ffa04221
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dealer_latitude"
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   08-12 11:22:13.054 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 7
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: 25.5571
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: --7d8bb6d6-ecaa-4e18-b219-0e02ffa04221
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dealer_longitude"
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 7
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: 77.1441
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: --7d8bb6d6-ecaa-4e18-b219-0e02ffa04221
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="add-dealer-submit"
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 3
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: abc
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: --7d8bb6d6-ecaa-4e18-b219-0e02ffa04221
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dealer_form_id"
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 6
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: 000566
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: --7d8bb6d6-ecaa-4e18-b219-0e02ffa04221
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dealer_pics"; filename="IMG_20170811_105147.jpg"
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Type: image/*
>   08-12 11:22:13.055 30327-31511/in.avprojects.formtest D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 65118
>   `

Comment: got a solution to this?